# problema con bloquear arreglos en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

Tengo un problema con los arreglos en angular, consumo un servicio que me trae datos y lo asigno a 2 arreglos:

1. arreglo que mostrare en la vista.
2. arreglo original para comparar y restaurar información.

> ```
> this.clientesService.getClientes().subscribe(
>     resp => {
>       this.total = resp.length;
>       this.clientes = resp;
>       this.clientesMostrar = this.clientes;
>     },
>     error => {
>       console.log(error);
>     });
> ```

despues de alterar el arreglo de la vista, lo quiero restaurar volviendole a asignar el arreglo original pero despues de asignarlo y cuando lo muestro a la vista me di cuenta que los mismos cambios que hice en los que mostraba se realizaban en el original.

lo que quiero sabes es como puedo bloquear o evitar que el original se altere. En teoria no deberia de pasar esto pero es raro que pase esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por defecto en Javascript todo se pasa por referencia, o sea, que al intentar copiar un objeto en otro lo que haces es apuntarlo a una nueva variable, por eso es que no puedes hacerlo así como lo estas haciendo.

Recomiendo hacer la copia de esta forma

```
this.clientesMostrar = Object.assign({}, this.clientes);
```

Comment: no pudo resolver el problema, pero me diste una idea como resolverlo usando `this.clientesMostrar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.cliente))` gracias.

Comment: Eso no te va a ayudar mucho, no sé qué estás intentando convirtiendo a string y a objeto de nuevo

Comment: pero me resulto, de todas formas muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás copiando el mismo array dos veces:

```
this.clientesService.getClientes().subscribe(
    resp => {
      this.total = resp.length;
      //copias la respuesta a clientes
      //lo que hubiese en clientes se ha perdido
      this.clientes = resp;
      //copias lo que hay en this clientes (que es lo mismo que resp)
      this.clientesMostrar = this.clientes;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Por tanto la solución es tan simple como cambiar el orden de las asignaciones:

```
this.clientesService.getClientes().subscribe(
    resp => {
      this.total = resp.length;
      //haces la "copia de seguridad"
      this.clientesMostrar = this.clientes;
      //te quedas con el nuevo valor
      this.clientes = resp;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```